NextJS 15 Link broken after cache invalidation
I am using NextJS App router to build my app. I use following server actions to load initial page data (getChatbot) and to mutate it (unlockChatbot). If I unlock the chatbot, it sends a request to our backend and sets an "unlocked" state in a client component.
// Chatbot Actions
export async function getChatbot(
  chatbotId: string,
): Promise<APIResponse<client.GetChatbotResponse>> {
    return await callAPI<client.GetChatbotResponse>(() =>
      zpps.chatbot.getChatbotChatbotIdGetRaw(
        {
          chatbotId,
        },
        { next: { tags: ["chatbot"] } },
      ),
    )
}

export async function unlockChatbot(
  chatbotId: string,
  displayWarning?: boolean,
): Promise<APIResponse<client.UnlockChatbotResponse>> {
    revalidateTag("chatbot")
    return await callAPI<client.UnlockChatbotResponse>(() =>
      zpps.chatbot.unlockChatbotChatbotIdUnlockPutRaw({
        chatbotId,
        unlockChatbotRequest: {
          displayWarning,
        },
      }),
    )
}

I also have side bar in my app with NextJS Link elements.
<Link
            key={link.name}
            prefetch={false}
            href={disabled ? "#" : link.href}
            onClick={(e) => {
              if (disabled) {
                e.preventDefault()
                setDialogOpen(true)
              }
            }}>
...
</Link>

The problem is that if I unlock the chatbot, the Links in side nav stop working for a few seconds, maybe a minute.
After a few seconds I see following warning in the browser console:
The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Then after another couple of seconds they start working again. If I remove the revalidateTag("chatbot"), the Links work instantly, but then I have problem when someone unlocks a chatbot, navigates somewhere else and then navigates back. Without revalidateTag the chatbot would be locked again until I reload the page.
Any tips on how to fix or at least debug this problem?
